# Get page name without the file suffix

Tags: javascript

How I can get rid of the file suffix(.html/.php etc) from page name?
I'm currently using this to get the page name

```
location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: I think the only way is to call your files `index.html` and point your page to the wanted directory, you won't have to specify the file name in this case (Only one `index.html` by directory of course). I don't know for php.

Comment: If you have `.` in your file names that will be tough, else this is easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
location.pathname.match(/(\w+)\.?\w*$/).pop()
```

A bit explanation:

`(\w+)` - this is the file name.

`\.?` - the dot that can be.

`\w*?` - the suffix that can be.

`$` - it has to be in the end of the url

Comment: This won't work if the filename has any non-alphanumeric characters like dashes or periods.

Comment: yes - for non-alphanumeric characters this will be good:  `location.pathname.match(/([^\/]+)\.?[^\/]*$/).pop()`

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple substring function to extract text from point 0 to the position of "." string.

```
var str = "yourfilename.html";
alert(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(".")));
```

Hope this serves your purpose.